# PHP remove only and only phone numbers from text

Tags: php, regex

This is a sample text/string with a mix of numbers and phone numbers:

> oh my god i have 1000 things to do today and i want to finish reading
>   20,000 Leagues Under the Sea, 1954 book, but hey, I will see you there
>   from 4pm to 8 my cell is 374-7657654 or you can call me at
>   (374)-334-5674 and then i can come from 16:30 thru 19:45 (in european
>   time!)

how do i remove/detect ONLY phone numbers (written in any format, since i can't foresee how a user would write them?

i tried

```
(\(?+[0-9]{3,15}+[\- ]?+[0-9]?+\)?+)
```

but it strips away the time or book title/ year etc

Comment: What makes a number a phone number? The `written in any format` makes this almost impossible..

Comment: i tried many solutions but it strips away the small digits

Comment: @chris85 is right. `The written in any format makes this almost impossible..`

Comment: @chris85 any number greater than 9 (at least in western countries) that can include characters like () - –

Comment: In your current example make the last number class not optional. `[0-9]+`..

Comment: @DanWhite my 6,720 points are because i'm a rookie and i ask LOT of basic questions ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the regex:

`1?\W*([2-9][0-8][0-9])\W*([2-9][0-9]{2})\W*([0-9]{4})(\se?x?t?(\d*))?`

```
preg_match("1?\W*([2-9][0-8][0-9])\W*([2-9][0-9]{2})\W*([0-9]{4})(\se?x?t?(\d*))?", "", $text);
```

Where `$text` is the text you wish to validate.

All credit to indiv, answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Did you just have that regex lying around?

Comment: I found the regex on a separate answer, and put it in preg_match.

Comment: Let me double check that regex @Francesco

Comment: I was looking for some thing similar vote up from me too, nice work

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer, why not come up with something easier:

```
~([-+()\d]{5,})~
# looks for -+() and digits 
# which need to be there at least 5 consecutive times
```

See [a demo here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jA9hN0/1).